# HaxeFlixel - issue with passing FlxTypedGroup into another FlxState

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

After passing `FlxTypedGroup` into new `FlxState` im getting this error message from new state :

```
Invalid field access : length
```

my code :

in GameState class after certain action:

```
FlxG.switchState(new EvaluationState(ingredients));
```

please note that `ingredients` is `FlxTypedGroup<Ingredient>` and its not empty.

in EvaluationState :

```
var ingredients:FlxTypedGroup<Ingredient>;
public function new(i:FlxTypedGroup<Ingredient>) 
{
    super();
    ingredients = i;
}

override public function create():Void 
{
    super.create();

    for (ing in ingredients)
    {
        trace(ing.active);
    }   
}
```

Also im getting `null` in `create()` function after calling `ingredients.members`.

Does anyone know how to pass `FlxTypedGroup` into new `FlxState` without destroying it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your group is being destroyed in another state when the switch occurs.

How is the previous state in which "ingredients" is created? If the group is added to this last state the most likely cause is that when switching it calls "destroy()" on ingredients.

Try to remove it from the state before passing is as parameter to EvaluationState to see if this solves your problem.

```
currentState.remove(ingredients); //This should prevent a null members
FlxG.switchState(new EvaluationState(ingredients));
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was thinking. It looks like that after switch old state is destroyed and correct me if im wrong, passing variables in haxe only point to memory where data are stored. So after base class is destroyed, all passed data are also destroyed. Anyway im getting nowhere from now

Comment: Yes, when switching, the current state will destroy anything that is inside its group (an FlxState is just a glorified FlxGroup) before making the switch to the new one. Did you try to use:

`currentState.remove(ingredients);`
`FlxG.switchState(new EvaluationState(ingredients));`

This should prevent it from being destroyed. If you notice, `members` is null because of the call to `destroy()` (from FlxGroup `line 121`):

`members = null;`

Could you try removing `ingredients` from the state before switching to see if it works?

Sorry for the incomplete comment earlier btw.

Comment: it looks like this could sovle it. Now im testing it.

Comment: Yes it did ! . Also i found another sollution by using FlxSubState. Thanks for your tips ! :)